# Check equal values in two different Columns on Google Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, compare

I was wondering how can I get the following result:

```
var X = [ex1, ex2, ex3, ex4];
var Y = [ex3, ex8, ex1, ex5];
```

Each one of the variables (X and Y) are in different sheets (Let's say, 'sheet' and 'sheet4'), at the column B of the respective sheet.

The output would be

```
= [ex3, ex1];
```

I then need to exclude the rows associated with ex1 and ex3 in sheet1.
I'm trying this, but the code returns nothing.

```
function check(){
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Página1");
    var sheet4 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Página4");
    var data1 = sheet.getRange("B1:B").getValues();
    var data4 = sheet4.getRange("B1:B").getValues();
    var lastrow1 = data1.filter(String).length;
    var lastrow4 = data4.filter(String).length;
    for (var i = 1; i <= lastrow1; i++){
        var email1 = sheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue();}
        for (var j = 1; j <= lastrow4; j++){
            var email4 = sheet4.getRange(j, 2).getValue();}
            if (email1[i] == email4[j]){
                sheet.deleteRow(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Of course it returns nothing - there is no `return` statement, and no outside code attempting to obtain a return value from it. Your code will also be really slow due to the nested for loop, and the use of `getValue` within the loops. You'll also skip rows since you modify the iterated object without compensating in your iterator.